# Missing asp-route-id value in asp-page for Delete in Razor Page .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have this very weird TournamentBatch Razor Page (index.cshtml) where we have something like this:

```
<td>
                <a asp-page="/TournamentBatchItems/Index" asp-route-id="@item.TournamentBatchID">Items</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.TournamentBatchID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.TournamentBatchID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.TournamentBatchID">Delete</a>
            </td>
```

and when we are running this and end up that there is no id returned on the page just for /Delete link and other links are ok (/TournamentBatchItems/Index, /Edit, /Details).

This is the html source looks like:

```
<td>
                <a href="/TournamentBatchItems?id=5088415a-f491-4438-1aa9-08d642f7dffe">Items</a> |
                <a href="/TournamentBatches/Edit?id=5088415a-f491-4438-1aa9-08d642f7dffe">Edit</a> |
                <a href="/TournamentBatches/Details?id=5088415a-f491-4438-1aa9-08d642f7dffe">Details</a> |
                <a href="">Delete</a> |
            </td>
```

Now other pages for Delete are OK only this page. ?!?!

Any ideas?

Index Pagemodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Data;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Models;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Utilities;
using CsvHelper;
using System.IO;

namespace AthlosifyWebArchery.Pages.TournamentBatches
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AthlosifyWebArchery.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(AthlosifyWebArchery.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<TournamentBatch> TournamentBatches { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            TournamentBatches = await _context.TournamentBatch.ToListAsync();
        }



    }
}
```

Delete Pagemodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Data;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Models;

namespace AthlosifyWebArchery.Pages.TournamentBatches
{
    public class DeleteModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AthlosifyWebArchery.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DeleteModel(AthlosifyWebArchery.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public TournamentBatch TournamentBatch { get; set; }
        public string ConcurrencyErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(Guid? id, bool? concurrencyError)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            TournamentBatch = await _context.TournamentBatch
                                        .AsNoTracking() //Addded
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TournamentBatchID == id);

            if (TournamentBatch == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (concurrencyError.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ConcurrencyErrorMessage = "The record you attempted to delete "
                  + "was modified by another user after you selected delete. "
                  + "The delete operation was canceled and the current values in the "
                  + "database have been displayed. If you still want to delete this "
                  + "record, click the Delete button again.";
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid? id)
        {
            /*if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            TournamentBatch = await _context.TournamentBatch.FindAsync(id);

            if (TournamentBatch != null)
            {
                _context.TournamentBatch.Remove(TournamentBatch);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            */

            try
            {
                if (await _context.TournamentBatch.AnyAsync(
                    m => m.TournamentBatchID == id))
                {
                    // Department.rowVersion value is from when the entity
                    // was fetched. If it doesn't match the DB, a
                    // DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception is thrown.
                    _context.TournamentBatch.Remove(TournamentBatch);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Delete",
                    new { concurrencyError = true, id = id });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code from Delete pagemodel.

Comment: BUT the link not even generated on Index page? Why it's gotta to do with the Delete page model? Anyway I've added the Delete pagemodel

Comment: Usually this happens when the anchor tag helper (in this case, `asp-page`) can't find the page or doesn't have a route match.  Check and make sure the `Delete.cshtml` page is in the same spot as `Edit` and `Details`, and that you've started your page with the `@page` directive, and that your page directive is in the correct syntax.  ex: `@page "{id:int}"`

Comment: @AdamVincent Thank you. We found the issue and you are right. We must be cut and paste the page directive it has the `@page "{id:int}"` instead of `@page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [Anchor Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Usually this happens when the anchor tag helper (in this case, asp-page) can't find the page or can't resolve the route through the default route conventions (you can find more details, or how to customize the conventions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

First check and make sure your `Delete.cshtml` page is in the same spot as `Edit.cshtml` and `Details.cshtml` (since they are working, and you used the same relative path for all 3.)

Also check and that you've started your page with the `@page` directive, and that your page directive is in the correct syntax which matches the appropriate method signature in your `PageModel`

example: `@page "{id:int}"`

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int id) 
{
...
}
```